# razor class library scaffolding views from external class library

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, portable-class-library, scaffolding

I have an asp.net core class lib `project.models` that has all the EF code first models.  Ideally, I would like to have a razor class library `project.views` that would handle all the views.

Could I scaffold the views in the RCL from an external EF class library?

#### or maybe the better question is...

Is there a way to scaffold razor pages from models within a razor class library?  I do not have the context menu option "New Scaffolding Item..." in the RCL